# jQuery selectors for even/odd rows in a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The code in the first Code Block is the source code. After the source code is running. The code will be changed (See the 2nd Code Block).

I want the class(i.e. 'even' and 'odd') of  tag is only displayed in the 'table1'. However, currently a nest table (i.e. 'table2') also has 'even' and 'odd' class of each  tag.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

**-----------First Code Block--------------**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#table1 tr:odd").addClass("odd");
                $("#table1 tr:not(.odd)").addClass("even");  
            });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="table2">
                   <tr></tr>
                   <tr></tr>
            <table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
```

**-----------2nd Code Block---------------**

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr class="even">
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>DDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>
            <table id="table2">
                   <tr class="even"></tr>
                   <tr class="odd"></tr>
            <table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You should give your question a more meaningful title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of the posted answer are almost right..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table1 > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#table1 > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").addClass("even");  
});
```

Many browsers automatically add a `tbody` to your table even if you don't add one yourself.  So `#table1 > tr` will not match because `tr` is not a direct child of `table`.  Your best bet is to use the above and explicitly add a `tbody` for those browsers that don't do it for you.

```
 <table id="table1">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>CCC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                <table id="table2">
                   <tbody>
                       <tr class="even"></tr>
                       <tr class="odd"></tr>
                   </tbody>
                <table>
            </td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>

</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ETAD/1/

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$("#table1>tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#table1>tr:not(.odd)").addClass("even");
```

Comment: This won't work:  http://jsfiddle.net/5ETAD/2/  tested in chrome and IE8 and it matches nothing.  The browsers internally add a `tbody`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid redundant DOM traversal, you could use something like this:

```
$('#table1 > tbody')
.filter('tr:odd').addClass('odd')
.end() //break chain and return to the original tbody element
.filter('tr:even').addClass('even')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following (notice the greater than sign):

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#table1 > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#table1 > tr:not(.odd)").addClass("even");  
        });
```

This will select only the immediate children tr's.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [direct child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector.

Also you can use :even instead of :not(.odd)

```
$(document).ready(function(){                 
  $("#table1 > tr:odd").addClass("odd");                 
  $("#table1 > tr:even").addClass("even");               
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            $("#table1 > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#table1 > tr:not(.odd)").addClass("even");
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use proper CSS selectors. Try:

```
$("#table1>tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```