# expanding on the multiple tables, jquery selector problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Expanding on this problem right here: [jQuery selectors for even/odd rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665867/jquery-selectors-for-even-odd-rows-in-a-table)

If the table from his example is a class and not an ID, say for dynamically created tables, how can one stop the :odd class from being added (incorrectly) to table 2?

http://jsfiddle.net/techii/hhWNE/10/

I want a "reset/clear" before the next table starts. That however is proving pretty difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table").find("tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $(".table").find("tbody > tr:even").hide();
    $(".table").find("tbody > tr:first-child").show();

    $(".table tr.odd").click(function() {
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    });
});
```

By not using a single selector, it resets the parity for each table.

Answer (score 0):

many ways, you can do a :first or .first() (if it's only the first table)

Comment: Well, I want the second table to show/hide rows aswell. The problem now is that it hides incorrectly because the :odd carries over (does not reset on a new `<table>` or even if they are seperated by `<div>'s`